# Limit Login attempts 3 times in play framework

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, playframework

I want to implement limit login attempts 3 times and if it exists then the user will be locked. How I can achieve that? is there any better way to do it?

```
if (!user.authCode.equals(User.hashPassword(login.authCode))) {
            flash("msg", "Password does not match.");
            return redirect(routes.Application.LoginForm());
}
```

Comment: what do you want to know?

Comment: Just for learning purpose. How it is done in play framework?

Comment: what do you want to know?

Comment: Limiting the login attempts using play framework. I can do it in session but is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution here is to store the number of remaining attempts in the database.

Because if you use the session, a user will be able to reconnect by clearing his browser cookies.